# display id and name via sql select statement

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

- i have 2 dropdown lists, 1 label & 1 textbox.
- on selection of 'product categories' @ 1st ddl, 2nd ddl displays all product categories.
- question is, how may i display the product category id @ the label, and name @ the textbox, on load/selection of 2nd ddl?
- i have the following code:

```
Public Sub FilterProductCategory()
    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dtrReader As SqlDataReader


    myConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT product_category_id, product_category_name FROM ProductCategory ORDER BY product_category_name"

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        dtrReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dtrReader.HasRows Then
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear()
            DropDownList2.DataSource = dtrReader
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "product_category_name"
            DropDownList2.DataBind()
        End If
        dtrReader.Close()
        myConn.Close()
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set this:

```
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "product_category_name"
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "product_category_id"
```

so when you try dropdownlist2.selectedvalue then you will get id and when u try dropdownlist2.selecteditem.text then it will give you product category name ..

hope it will solve your problem

Comment: the above 3 suggestions works fine now. Now my issue is, only after selection @ ddl2, then the changes reflect.

On load, it does not. Currently the id displays at both label & textbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, sound simple enough. I am assuming that the ID of you label and textbox follow the same format as the dropdownlist. If not please substitute you own ID's. Also this code runs entirely server side which means you will refresh the entire page just to accomplish this fairly simple task. If this is not an issue then by all means use this method otherwise I'd recommend using javascript on the client side for this.

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(Sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged
Label1.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
TextBox1.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: the above 3 suggestions works fine now. Now my issue is, only after selection @ ddl2, then the changes reflect.

On load, it does not. Currently the id displays at both label & textbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First Set [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) to your dropdownlist `display text`(CategoryName) and [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) to your dropdownlist `SelectedValue`(categoryID).

```
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "product_category_name";
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "product_category_id";
```

and on the `SelectIndexChanged Event` of DropDownList use the `SelectedValue` property to access the `category ID` amd `SelectedItem.Text` to access the `Categoryname`

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(Sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged
Label1.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
TextBox1.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
```

Check [DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) for information about these properties with example.

Check this example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindList();
            }
        }

        private void BindList()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=test;integrated security=true;");
            SqlDataReader reader;
            SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * from UserTable order by UserName";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = reader;
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "userid";
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }

                reader.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```

output///

[image]

Comment: the above 3 suggestions works fine now. Now my issue is, only after selection @ ddl2, then the changes reflect.

On load, it does not. Currently the id displays at both label & textbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: check that the field name that you are specifying should match with table column name.. if everything ok then share your field datatype here..or set the field data type .. see the datalist documentation link to understand this as i told you in the answer..